# how to send email using keystone-nodemailer

Tags: keystonejs

I have installed [keystone-nodemailer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keystone-nodemailer) on my keystone site.

But the documentation is very  poor. and no one is talking about it on net.

The docs only said this.

```
keystone.set('email nodemailer', {
   // Nodemailer configuration
});
```

but don't say that  what to write as Nodemailer configuration. I know my smtp server, port username and password. but where to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this artical](https://gist.github.com/jeffreypriebe/238e384573136aa7d37a#file-model-js-L20) as  good answer for the question.

It seems the keystone core email component only works with mandrill. And if we bypass that then we have to do everything.

This guy had shown a way by which we can replace keystone-nodemailer as mandrill.

Based on  this article I have created  a [node module](https://github.com/enraiser/keystone-enmailer)

In short, the answer to the question is here.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer'),
smtp = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport'),

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtp({
   host: 'us2.smtp.mailhostbox.com',
   port: 587,
   secure: false,
   ignoreTLS: true,
   auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS
   }
}));
```

Comment: So then you pass the transport to keystone-nodemailer,  right?

Comment: Yes, I have not tested but it may work as part of keystone.set('email nodemailer',{}) as originally asked by me. in next project I will test it from begining.

Answer (score 1):

Those options are used to create the transport: https://github.com/bgag/keystone-nodemailer/blob/master/index.js#L20

So you should just put the [Nodemailer transport options](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer#setting-up) in there.

Also, create a PR with an example configuration in the `README.md` of `keystone-nodemailer`

Comment: I know those  options are used to create transport. but nothing is working. Can you give me code snippet ?

Comment: @enRaiser can you post a snippet that is not working? I don't use this project…

Comment: I just answerd my own  question above. may be its usefull to you too.